# Стили для пагинации не на всех страницах верные

Tags: html, css, css3

Приветствую. Есть у меня в коде стандартная пагинация. В момент, когда нахожусь на странице отличной от первой и последней все отображается хорошо, но когда нахожусь на первой/последней правило стилей: `:first-child` и `:last-child` начинает действовать на не тот элемент списка (т.к. или prev или next исчезают). Как это можно поправить с помощью стилей без php, скриптов и желательно без правки html ?

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.pagination li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.pagination ul.page-numbers>li:first-child,
.pagination ul.page-numbers>li:last-child {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue";
  width: 72px;
  height: 34px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #979567;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.pagination ul.page-numbers>li:first-child {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.pagination ul.page-numbers>li>a.prev,
.pagination ul.page-numbers>li>a.next {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue";
  width: 72px;
  height: 34px;
  color: #979567;
}
.pagination ul>li>a.prev:before {
  content: "пред";
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue";
}
.pagination ul>li>a.next:before {
  content: "след";
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue";
}
.pagination ul.page-numbers>li {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.pagination .page-numbers {
  display: table;
}
.pagination ul>li>a.page-numbers {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
}
.pagination ul>li>a.page-numbers:hover {
  background-color: #979567;
  color: #fff;
}
.pagination ul>li>.page-numbers.current {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #979567;
  color: #979567;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="pagination">
  <ul class="page-numbers">
    <li><span class="page-numbers current">1</span>
    </li>
    <li><a class="page-numbers" href="http://catalog/page/2/">2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="page-numbers" href="http://catalog/page/3/">3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="page-numbers" href="http://catalog/page/4/">4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="next page-numbers" href="http://catalog/page/2/"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.pagination li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.pagination ul.page-numbers>li:first-child,
.pagination ul.page-numbers>li:last-child {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue";
  width: 72px;
  height: 34px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #979567;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.pagination ul.page-numbers>li:first-child {
  margin-right: -20px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}
.pagination ul.page-numbers>li>a.prev,
.pagination ul.page-numbers>li>a.next {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue";
  width: 72px;
  height: 34px;
  color: #979567;
}
.pagination ul>li>a.prev:before {
  content: "пред";
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue";
}
.pagination ul>li>a.next:before {
  content: "след";
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue";
}
.pagination ul.page-numbers>li {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.pagination .page-numbers {
  display: table;
}
.pagination ul>li>a.page-numbers {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
.pagination ul>li>a.page-numbers:hover {
  background-color: #979567;
  color: #fff;
}
.pagination ul>li>.page-numbers.current {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #979567;
  color: #979567;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="pagination">
  <ul class="page-numbers">
    <li><span class="page-numbers current">1</span>
    </li>
    <li><a class="page-numbers" href="http://catalog/page/2/">2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="page-numbers" href="http://catalog/page/3/">3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="page-numbers" href="http://catalog/page/4/">4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="next page-numbers" href="http://catalog/page/2/"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Посмотри, такой вариант не подойдет:  .pagination ul.page-numbers>li:first-child { margin-right: -20px; margin-top: -5px; }

Comment: смотрите как будет выглядеть ваш код, если перейти на 2ую страницу http://jsfiddle.net/zssvmx0u/1/